# GUI doesn't close when i hit the button

Tags: tkinter, python-3.8

I want it so that the number changes to let the GUI open and close, but it only opens a new 1, and it won't close.

here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

screen = Tk()

InOpen = 1

def onclick(event):
    if event == 1:
        InOpen = 2
        InFrame = Frame(screen, width=500, height=350, bg="black")
        InFrame.pack()
    if event == 2:
        InFrame.destroy()
        InOpen = 1

mST = Label(screen, text="Minecraft", bg="grey", fg="white")
mST.pack(fill=X)

topFrame = Frame(screen)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(screen)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

button1 = Button(topFrame, text="Inventory", fg="blue", command=lambda:onclick(InOpen))
button2 = Button(topFrame, text="Combat", fg="red")

button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The shown code doesn't work just because in the function `onclick` the variables `InOpen` and `InFrame` are local, not global as intended. We have to declare that globals are meant:

```
def onclick(event):
    global InOpen, InFrame
    …
```